# NSCoder for unsigned integers with swift

Tags: swift, nscoder

In my swift app, I really need to store a UInt32 value and retrieve it using NSCoder.
The issue is, there are methods for signed integers :

```
coder.decodeInteger()
coder.decodeInt32()
coder.decodeInt64()
```

but not for unsigned integers.
Also, casting an Int32 of negative value in an UInt32 does not seem to work.

Am I missing some point?

Comment: How about converting the signed integers to unsigned just after decoding, and converting the unsigned integers to signed ones just before encoding?

Answer (score 0):

The tool you want is `init(bitPattern:)`. This is the same as C-style casting on integers (which is how you use these methods in ObjC when you need unsigned ints). It just reinterprets the bits.

```
UInt32(bitPattern: coder.decodeInt32())
```